# SIGXFSZ on ideone.com?

Tags: c++

I want to print repeated characters in a string in ascending order. This code compiles but gives a `SIGXFSZ` runtime error with no output on online c++ compilers... any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned int i;
  char str[26];
  int a[26];
  for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    a[i]=0;
A:
  i=0;
  cout<<"Enter the string:";
  cin>>str[i];

  while(str[i]!=13)
  {
    if(isalpha(str[i]))
      i++;
    else{
      cout<<"Invalid string";
      goto A;
    }
  }

  cout<<"You Enterd:"<<str;

  for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    ++a[str[i]-97];

  cout<<"\nLetters Frequency:";

  for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";

  cout<<"\nDuplicates in sorted order:";

  for(i=0;i<26;i++)
  {
    if(a[i]>1)
      cout<<char(i+97);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code next time.  Instructions are right beside the text box you used to enter your question.

Comment: `goto A;` - *Gasp!* [Obligatory XKCD.](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: Usually "online" C++ compilers don't support reading from `cin`. Have you tried this on your own computer?

Comment: Sometimes, rarely, a goto is clearer than what you have to do to avoid it.  This is not one of those times.

Comment: ugh dont EVER use a goto!!! http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GotoConsideredHarmful

Comment: @Greg: to submit code that uses `cin` on ideone, you can click on a link below the textbox to specify the data to pass on standard input.

Answer (score 2):

***Problem 1***

```
char str[26];
//..
cout<<"Enter the string:";
// should be cin >> str if you want to input a string,
// cin >> str[i] is used to input a single character only.
cin>>str[i];
```

***Problem 2***

```
// should be while(str[i]!='\0')
// because a C-style string is terminated with '\0'.
while(str[i]!=13)
{
  if(isalpha(str[i]))
    i++;
  else{
     cout<<"Invalid string";
     goto A;
  }
}
```

***Problem 3***

*Don't get used to `goto`*. It's not considered as a good programming style in most cases, as it make your code unnecessarily complicated, hard to read.

You can use the following loop to replace `goto`.

```
bool isInvalid = true;
while (isInvalid)
{
  // read input
  // while-loop validating the input

  if (str[i] == '\0') isInvalid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll get a `SIGXFSZ` on ideone if you don't end your input with valid input, because you will try to read more data than is available on `cin`. Here's a [working run](http://ideone.com/BdjnB#li_WDRTh).

Aside from that, I fixed a couple other bugs: First, the `cin >> str[i]` that Eric Z pointed out. Additionally, your `while(str[i]!=13)` should be `while(str[i]!=0)`.